# Webpack Same Loader, Different Rules

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babel-loader, vue-loader, string-replace-loader

I want to use the same loader for two of my rules.

My Vue files need to use vue-loader, and my js files need to use babel-loader. I want to be able to inject my API endpoint using string-replace-loader in both of them.

When I try to add both, it fails.

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        'vue-loader',
        {
            loader: 'string-replace-loader',
            options: {
                search: 'API_URL',
                replace: apiUrl,
                flags: 'g',
            },
        },
    ],
},
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        'babel-loader',
        {
            loader: 'string-replace-loader',
            options: {
                search: 'API_URL',
                replace: apiUrl,
                flags: 'g',
            },
        },
    ],
},
```